# Code first one to many self reference WillCascadeOnDelete Error

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a one to many self reference using EF6 code first. My entity looks like this

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Target { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }   
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public int? ParentMenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Menu> ChildMenus { get; set; }
}
```

And in my context class I do this to make the self reference with WillCascadeOnDelete(true)

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.ParentMenu)
            .WithMany(c => c.ChildMenus)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentMenuId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But when i update database in package manager console it's give an error

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Menus_dbo.Menus_ParentMenuId' on table 'Menus' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WVsH.jpg)

Comment: You have `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`. What's the question?

Comment: I recive error when i am update database in package manager console

Comment: You're still not asking anything, only telling a little story. You want cascaded delete, SQL server tells you you can't and even explains why not. Really, I'm not trying to nag you but I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: My question is that - why i receive error in package manager console

Comment: What i should change in my model

Comment: What about `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`?

Answer (score 1):

***Finally i found that there is no any way in code first self reference entity Cascade Delete ,i ought to write recursive function for cascade deleting***

Comment: It's not a code-first restriction, it's a SQL-Server restriction.